# How Might Tracing A Function Affect What It Does?

Tags: clojure

I defined a function `play` like so:

```
(let [play-switch (fn [c]
                (condp = c
                    :scales (play-scale)
                    :intervals (play-interval)
                    :chords (play-chord)
                    :inversions (play-inversion)
                    (print "play error, invalid :practice_mode state")))]
(def ^:dynamic play 
  "if no argument, evaluates the appropriate play-<mode> function, based on the current state of @opts.
   if one argument, does the corresponding play-<mode> function."
  (fn 
    ([] (play-switch (get @opts :practice_mode)))
    ([method] (play-switch method)))))
```

When I call `play` in my application like `(play)`, its intended side effect does not occur. However, when I `play` in my application like `(clojure.tools.trace/dotrace [play] (play))`. How could tracing a function affect what it does?

Answer (score 2):

Tracing a function can force the realization of otherwise unrealized lazy sequences.

Such problems are very commonly instances of "**the dreaded lazy bug**" where the side effects (aka the work) of one of the functions is being run in a lazy sequence. This has the frusterating effect that if you call the function directly from the REPL **the side effect happens as the result is printed** and if you call it with trace the lazy sequence is realized when trace prints the result. Though in the normal case the side effects never happen because the lazy sequence it not realized.

put calls to `doall` (if you need the result) or `dorun` (if you don't need the result) around each side effecting lazy sequence.